# Cannot match a date in a range using MATCH function and VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write a user defined function that returns the value in a range given a series ID and a date.

The range looks something like this

[image]

I would like the function call `=getParam("B",1/07/2005,Parameters)` to return `22`.

To do this, I am using a couple of `=MATCH` functions to find the correct row and column and then will use an `=INDEX` function to return the correct value.  My function (not complete) is below.

The problem:

When I specify `=MATCH(1/07/2005,A1:A11,0)` in a normal Excel cell I get the correct row index of `6`, but when I incorporate this inside my VBA function as per below, I get a `#VALUE!` error.

Any ideas?

```
Function getParam(Series As String, StartDate As Date, Parameters As Range)

    Dim IndexRow, IndexColumn As Integer

    IndexRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(StartDate, Parameters.Columns(1), 0)
    IndexColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Series, Parameters.Rows(1), 0)

    getParam = IndexRow

End Function
```

Comment: A few questions: 1. How do you call your Function? Give an example. 2. Why do you have IndexColumn seeing as you don't use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to convert your date into double to match it `CDbl(StartDate)`
2. The [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match) returns a `Double` therefore

   ```
   Dim IndexRow As Double, IndexColumn As Double
   ```

   you need to specify the type for **both** variables otherwise the first is automatically `Variant`.
3. Use a test procedure to feed your UDF (user defined function) if you want to debug it.

You end up with …

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test_getParam()
    Debug.Print getParam("B", DateSerial(2019, 7, 5), Range("A1:E13"))
End Sub

Public Function getParam(Series As String, StartDate As Date, Parameters As Range) As Variant
    Dim IndexRow As Double, IndexColumn As Double

    IndexRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CDbl(StartDate), Parameters.Columns(1), 0)
    IndexColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Series, Parameters.Rows(1), 0)

    getParam = Parameters.Cells(IndexRow, IndexColumn)
End Function
```

---

In your formula you need to submit a real date `DATE(2019,7,5)`

```
=getParam("B",DATE(2019,7,5),A1:E13) 'returns 10 with the data below
```

because if you submit `=getParam("B",1/07/2005,Parameters)` your "date" is `1/07/2005` which actually means `1` devided by `7` devided by `2005` with the result of `0.0000712504453153…` so this is the value you actually tried to match. You must use `DATE(2005,7,1)` to get a real date.

[image]

---

As a final improvement I recommend to include an error handling, to return an error if either date or series didn't match.

This will return error `#NA` if one of these didn't match.

```
Public Function getParam(Series As String, StartDate As Date, Parameters As Range) As Variant
    Dim IndexRow As Double, IndexColumn As Double

    On Error Resume Next
    IndexRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CDbl(StartDate), Parameters.Columns(1), 0)
    IndexColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Series, Parameters.Rows(1), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If IndexRow > 0 And IndexColumn > 0 Then
        getParam = Parameters.Cells(IndexRow, IndexColumn)
    Else
        getParam = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Guess it doesn't matter much but won't MATCH return a Long (or an error)?

Comment: @SJR  I assumed a `Long` too but according to the documentation (I linked in my answer) `WorksheetFunction.Match` returns a `Double` or throws an exeption (it does not return an error value). • Actually I have no idea why it returns a `Double` because for row or column number a `Long` should be sufficient.

Comment: So it does. Does seem a bit strange, but I suppose Long is a subset of Double.

Comment: @SJR Yep, really strange. I never found a use case where this result should be `Double`  or why it has any advantage over beeing `Long`. Actually `Long` uses 4 bytes while `Double` uses 8 bytes which should be a reason for `Long`, also a row/column number cannot be a floating point number.

Comment: Perhaps not the sort of thing MS would bother to change after all this time, or perhaps you're the only person to have noticed!